# Output plugin post like system count

Tags: plugins, post-meta

I am working with [WordPress Post Like System](https://github.com/JonMasterson/WordPress-Post-Like-System) plugin for user likes on a post.

I am wondering if there is a way to just output the post likes count without using the shortcode? Just showing the number of likes as text.

I'm not sure how to approach this but any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [plugin's readme file](https://github.com/JonMasterson/WordPress-Post-Like-System/blob/master/README.md), you can call a PHP function in your theme to display the likes, but that includes the buttons. Looking into that function shows the like count is coming directly from post meta, so you can use the same query the plugin uses to get the count:

```
$like_count = get_post_meta( $post_id, "_post_like_count", true );
```

In your theme where you want to print the count, you can use

```
echo esc_html( $like_count );
```

Comment: Hi morganestes! You're a very smart and kind person. This worked great! Thanks for the help! :) Best of luck!